# Copy files from a zip folder to another folder in nant

Tags: nant

I want to copy the files from the zip folder to another folder. 
I am doing this , but it doesn't works

```
    <copy todir="Lib">
<fileset basedir="Output/RCxSL.Client.zip/ServiceClientDlls">
    <include name="*.dll" />
</fileset>
    </copy>
```

How to achieve this ? the folder is  zipped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A ZIP folder is not a folder, it is a ZIP file, even though the operating system (through your files explorer) may make it look like a folder. Instead of using `<fileset>` and `<copy>`, use the [unzip task of NAnt](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/0.85-rc3/help/tasks/unzip.html).

```
<unzip zipfile="Output/RCxSL.Client.zip" todir="Lib" />
```

Comment: after unzipping the zip file can i copy the wanted files iniside it to another destination?

Comment: @Malcolm - yes, after unzipping you can work with the files using copy, they're now part of the file system.